# Heroku: How to change a Git remote on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I do not want to upload my app to the wrong domain.

How can I change the git master branch on git?

Comment: Yes. I have created a new heroku app: heroku create myapp. But I have another app on heroku. I just want to change the git master to the new app. So that i can say git push heroku master. And the code will be oploaded to the new app not the old one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace remote git repo (Heroku)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265493/replace-remote-git-repo-heroku)

Answer (score 201):

If you're working on the `heroku` remote (default):

```
heroku git:remote -a [app name]
```

If you want to specify a different remote, use the `-r` argument:

```
heroku git:remote -a [app name] -r [remote]
```

EDIT: thanks to  Алексей Володько For pointing it out that there's no need to delete the old remote.

Comment: Just followed this approach and appears to be the CURRENT correct way to do it.

Comment: As there was no correct answer designated by OP and this answer is by-in-large the answer to OP's question and has more upvotes than the "top" answer above does, why is this answer still shown below the lesser agreed upon answer? Thanks.

Comment: No need even to remove the old git remote. `heroku git:remote -a appname` - will replace the old one just fine.

Answer (score 108):

Assuming your current remote is named `origin` then:

Delete the current remote reference with

```
git remote rm origin
```

Add the new remote

```
git remote add origin <URL to new heroku app>
```

push to new domain

```
git push -u origin master
```

The `-u` will set this up as tracked.

Comment: How do I know what my origin is named?

Comment: can you explain what you meant here `The -u will set this up as tracked.` Thanks!

Comment: @uDay It means that when you ask for a pull, it will know to fetch and merge this branch

Comment: I would update this answer to remove the heroku remote initially - not the git remote origin master...

Answer (score 24):

1. **View Remote URLs**

   `> git remote -v`

```
    heroku  https://git.heroku.com/###########.git (fetch) < your Heroku Remote URL
    heroku  https://git.heroku.com/############.git (push)
    origin  https://github.com/#######/#####.git (fetch) < if you use GitHub then this is your GitHub remote URL
    origin  https://github.com/#######/#####.git (push)
```

2. **Remove Heroku remote URL**

   `> git remote rm heroku`
3. **Set new Heroku URL**

   `> heroku git:remote -a  ############`

*And you are done.*

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
git remote set-url heroku <repo git>
```

This replacement old url heroku.

You can check with:

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple applications on heroku and want to add changes to a particular application, run the following command :
**heroku git:remote -a appname**
and then run the following.

1. git add . 2)git commit -m "changes" 3)git push heroku master

Source:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many branches you want, just as a regular git repository, but according to heroku docs, any branch other than `master` will be ignored.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

> Branches pushed to Heroku other than
>   master will be ignored. If you’re
>   working out of another branch locally,
>   you can either merge to master before
>   pushing, or specify that you want to
>   push your local branch to a remote
>   master.

This means that you can push anything you want, but you app at heroku will always point to the master branch.

But, if you question regards how to create branches and to work with git you should check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: How do I change the git master?

Comment: What do you mean by that? by `change the git master` you mean changes files, then commit and push to it? rename it? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Just saw your comment on the question, your are having problems with remote, and not with branches... check @Abizern's answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**Remove Heroku remote URL from git repo**

 > git remote rm heroku

**Set new Heroku URL from git repo**

 > git remote add heroku ##########

Answer (score 1):

here is a better answer found through Git docs.

This shows what the heroku remote is:

$ git remote get-url heroku

Found it here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote
Also in that document is a set-url, if you need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

write in terminal if you already login with heroku from terminal..
heroku git:remote -a **appname**