# Replace remote git repo (Heroku)

Tags: git, heroku

i'm new to git and heroku.

I've created an app on heroku, pushed some files to the repo.

Now I want fully replace this app's repo with new content from another folder (and have a .git repo in that folder). What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to completely replace the history of the commits you already pushed by the history of that new second repo, all you should need to do would be:

```
git remote show heroku in the first repo
cd /path/to/seconf/git/repo
git remote add heroku <heroku_repo_address_from_previous_command>
# for instance: git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git
git push --force heroku master
```

That would replace the `master` branch of the remote `heroku` repo by the `master` branch of your second repo. But that would loose (or at least keep in reflogs of the remote repo for a while) the history of the `master` branch of the former repo.

This assume you can reuse your heroku credentials you already created, following the [Heroku quick start page](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart) and the [Heroku Deploying with git page](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Comment: Thanks. is --force option gives 100% grantee that new master branch wont be merged with old one on server but just replace it? from docs it is not obvious ("This flag [-f,--force] disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.")

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: yes, there won't be any merge.

Comment: Just needed to use "the force"