# Completely replace heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Ive just finished coding a version 2 of my rails app on heroku and am now looking to upload it.

Is there anyway to completely replace my old one on heroku? The new app has a completely new database.

Comment: why dont you just recreate it ?? (delete - create new)

Comment: @TheMiniJohn I dont want to lose everything I have set up as far as addons

Comment: Then you can normally push it (overwriting the existing repo) and just reset the DB..

Comment: @TheMiniJohn `rake db:reset`? Doesnt that build off an old migration or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can normally push you new code and then just reset your database.

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

then recreate the database with nothing in it:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If you want to completely replace the history of the commits you already pushed by the history of that new second repo, all you should need to do would be:

```
git remote show heroku in the first repo
cd /path/to/seconf/git/repo
git remote add heroku <heroku_repo_address_from_previous_command>
# for instance: git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git
git push --force heroku master
```

That would replace the `master` branch of the remote `heroku` repo by the `master` branch of your second repo. But that would loose (or at least keep in reflogs of the remote repo for a while) the history of the `master` branch of the former repo.

See -> [Replace remote git repo (Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265493/replace-remote-git-repo-heroku)

Comment: how do I push my new code if I built the second app in a new folder on my computer?

Comment: What if I already have pushed it once somewhere else on heroku, can I change the second ones heroku to point somewhere else?

Comment: Nvm figured it out `git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git`